# How to merge DataSet tables in the same DataSet

Tags: c#

I have a similar post already that brought up this new question. I see examples of merging dataset tables with other datases but how can you do so with a table in that set? I have posted below my code. How can I merge the IncomingProdcutTotals and the IncomingProdcutTotals1 tables?

```
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

da.Fill(ds);

ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

ds.Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: 1) Merge a Table with a Table, not with a DS. 2) Merge before Remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `DataSet.Merge`:

```
ds.Tables["IncomingProdcutTotals"].Merge(ds.Tables["IncomingProdcutTotals1"]);
```

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos because you want to merge a table into another table, not a table into another `DataSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the data table with another data table, not with a dataset

```
ds.tables["IncomingProdcutTotals"].Merge(ds.tables["IncomingProdcutTotals1"]);
```

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)